# cant change my screen resolution

Tags: 12.04, resolution, monitor, settings

Hi i have a problem with my screen resolution after installing ubuntu 12.04
I think i have the right drivers, but for some reason the resolution is way to small. It is 640 x 480 and thats the only option under "Monitors".
How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you open terminal (ctrl+alt+t), enter 'xrandr' (without quotes) and add output to your question?

Answer (score 2):

I worked out a fix and here it is:

Open up a shell :

```
$ xrandr
```

(This will show you your connection type, in my case it's VGA1)

```
$ cvt 1680 1050 60
```

(Just type this in and hit enter, my refresh rate is 60. My resolution can handle 1680x1050. Copy the part after 'Modeline' e.g.
**Modeline "1680x1050_60.00" 146.25 1680 1784 1960 2240 1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync**
then add this to the following command.

```
$ xrandr --newmode "1680x1050" 146.25 1680 1784 1960 2240 1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync
```

(**Notice how I took out the "_60.00"** part after "1680x1050" above? It only works if you take out that refresh bit.)

```
$ xrandr --addmode VGA1 1680x1050
```

(This should add the new resolution you used to get, my monitor only gets to 1680x1050. The VGA1 is the connection type you get in the first command i mentioned. You might have something like hdmi1 or something.)

Comment: Hmm still problems apparently. after i entered the command: $ xrandr --newmode "1680x1050" 146.25 1680 1784 1960 2240 1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync It gave me the message: "xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default"

Comment: got this error after the second command

  $ xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default

Comment: Just FYI : This worked like a charm for me using Ubuntu 13.10 too.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

Reboot your machine afterwards.

Comment: okay it says that linux-headers-generic is already the newest version and that nothing will be installed. hmm..?

Comment: I entered xrandr in the terminal and got the followiing output:
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 240, current 640 x 480, maximum 640 x 480
default connected 640x480+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   640x480        50.0* 
   320x240        51.0